# How to use address to elf entry point in Rust?

Tags: rust, operating-system, osdev

So, I am porting my hobby OS from C and C++ to Rust. I am using the rust libraries uefi rs and elf rs to make a bootloader. I have gotten to the point that I have my kernel elf file loaded, and I have gotten the entry point using

```
let mut kernel_start_point = header.entry_point();
```

But now, with C I was able to do this to actually use this entry point:

```
void (*KernelStart)() = ((__attribute__((sysv_abi)) void(*)()) header.e_entry);
KernelStart();
```

Just to be sure there is enough info, this is my current kernel code:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

My question is, is it possible to do something similar in rust? And how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Something like `let kernel_start: extern "C" fn() = transmute (kernel_start_point); kernel_start();`?

Comment: I believe it is being called but any code I put in the kernel does not get executed.